# how to have fixed height divs using 960.gs?

Tags: css, frameworks, height, 960.gs

I am using 960.gs to do the layout of a simple page, but am having a hard time enforcing a maximum height for the DIVs I am using. Consider the following:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="text.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="960.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="topContainer" class="container_12">

  <div style="height:200; overflow:hidden" class="grid_10">

  <!-- lots of text or a large image-->

  </div>

  <div class="grid_2"> <!-- rhs col--> </div>
</div>
```

How can I enforce a specific height for this div? I have tried setting the "height" property on the top-level container, but that didn't help, either.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten the unit on your height parameter:

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow:hidden" class="grid_10">
```

Answer (score 0):

this question interests me also very mutch..

its ofthen comming situation that **dynamic layout-columns must have automatic max height**.

it would be very nice if u publish a list of aproaches about this problem.

cya pascal